# Can I close my lightbox when the mouse is clicked on the outside area (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css

This lightbox functions fine, but I'm curious how to close it, without Javascript, whenever the surrounding area is clicked.  It's simple enough to accomplish with Javascript/JQuery, but I wanted to see how it could be done without either.  Thanks

```
    .black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        left: 20%;
        width: 55%;
        height: 55%;
        padding: 16px;
        border:  1px solid lightgray;
        background-color: white;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }

<body>
    <p> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">click here</a></p>
    <div id="light" class="white_content">Content and stuff. <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google of ***CSS only lightbox*** turned up this interesting code pen example by **Gregory Schier** (full credit)

http://codepen.io/gschier/pen/HCoqh

Gregory is using the `:target` psuedo-class selector to show the light box, by setting its display attribute to `block` and thus rendering the light box visible.

```
.lightbox {
    display: none;
}

.lightbox:target {
    display: block;
}
```

The target state of the lightbox is triggered by the `<a>` that wraps the thumbnail image. This is done by referencing the lightboxs' id in the anchors `href` attribute, as described [by this W3C guide](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

```
<a href="#[LIGHTBOX_ID]">
  <img src="../path/to/image-thumbnail.jpg">
</a>

<a href="#_" id="[LIGHTBOX_ID]">
  <img src="..path/to/image-full.jpg">
</a>
```

Don't forget to prefix the lightbox id ih the href attribute of the link wrapping the thumbnail with a `#` (as pictured above).

Again, full credit to **Gregory Schier**

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS-only solution, you might adopt CSS `:focus` as a (slightly contrived) substitute for Javascript `onclick`.

Of course, the `<p>` element does not support `:focus` naturally, so it's also necessary to add `contentEditable="true"`, so that it can accept `:focus`:

```css
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 55%;
    height: 55%;
    padding: 16px;
    border:  1px solid lightgray;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}

p {
display: inline-block;
}

a {
color: rgb(0,0,255);
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: underline;
}

p:focus ~ #light, p:focus ~ #fade {
display: block;
cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<p contentEditable="true"><a>Click here</a></p>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
<div id="light" class="white_content">Content and stuff. <a>Close</a></div>
```